# How to assign Map<String, T> in class using a generic function without casting

Tags: java, generics

I am working on some code.
I have a class like this.

```java
class Document {

//assume there are getters and setters
Map<String, Number> idToRatings;
Map<String, String> idToNames;

public <T> void setNewMapAttribute(Function<Map<String, T>, Map<String, T>> mapConsumer){
        this.setIdToRatings((Map<String, Number>) mapConsumer.apply((Map<String, T>) this.idToRatings()));
        this.idToNames((Map<String, String>) mapConsumer.apply((Map<String, T>) this.idToNames()));

    }
}
```

Then in an another class I have a function like this.

```java
private <T> Map<String, T> filterMapKeys(Map<String, T> givenMap) {
        return givenMap
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(stringTEntry -> attributeIds.contains(stringTEntry.getKey()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
    }
```

This method would then be used like this ideally

```java
doucment.setNewMapAttribute(this::filterMapKeys);
```

I would like to create a way where I can filter any of properties in the class by a list of ids. Since the Maps in `Document` contain different key values, I need to use generics. The code in the end would take in a list of ids like `List.of("123", "456")` and return a Document that only has the ids 123 and 456 in either of it's properties. However, intellij is requiring the casting in `setNewMapAttribute` which I would like to avoid.

Is there anything I can do about this casting? Is there a different type of generic signature I can use to make the function work without the casting?

It makes sense to me that if my function only uses the key type of the Map, then I should be able to filter on ids within all attributes without the casting seen in `setNewMapAttribute`. The type of the value in Maps, does not concern my filtering function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly understood requirements...

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface MapFilter {

    <T> Map<String, T> filter(Map<String, T> map);

}

public void setNewMapAttribute(MapFilter mapConsumer) {
    this.setIdToRatings(mapConsumer.filter(this.getIdToRatings()));
    this.setIdToNames(mapConsumer.filter(this.getIdToNames()));
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. Could you explain to me why this worked vs why my code didn't? What difference is there between defining the functional interface vs having `Function<Map<String, T>, Map<String, T>>`  as a method attribute.

Comment: `Function<Map<String, T>, Map<String, T>>` is Generic Type, `<T> Map<String, T> filter(Map<String, T> map)` - Generic Method, different concepts.